# Cannot connect to SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) on UWP

Tags: sql-server, uwp, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

I installed SQLEXPRESS on my system and can access it through Azure Data Studio and server explorer on Visual Studio. But when I try connecting to it using its connection string on a UWP app (.netstandard 2.0.3, EF-core 3.1.17) it throws an error.

[image: Visual Studio server explorer]

[image: Azure Data Studio Connection]

[image: Connection String]

Comment: Have you refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases) before and enable  Enterprise Authentication capability?

Comment: Just did it and it didn't help

Comment: is the server in the local network or remote network?

Comment: local network. I am using sql express

Comment: Please make sure you have enabled the network loopback for the app. for detail steps please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback)

Comment: And please make sure you have enable private network capability